QueueTrigger not firing in Azure with Managed Identities
I have a function app running locally without any problems:
public async Task Run([QueueTrigger("update-or-add-vessel", Connection = "QueueConnection")] QueueMessage vesselJson)
{
}

This is my local host:
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated",
    "NotifyCron": "0 0 3 * * WED",
    "Cron": "0 0 7,12,17 * * *",
    "QueueConnection__queueServiceUri": "https://xxx.queue.core.windows.net"
  }

I copied settings to Azure:

}
The queue has messages but the function never triggers.
The functions managed identity has processing permissions on the storage queue:

Any ideas on whats missing or how to trouble shoot? No messages goes to poison queue, its like the function app just not trigger at all.

You haven't included it in your question,  so I'm just stabbing here. But, given you mentioned it works locally, and I suspect you're using a SAS token or account key when developing locally, make sure you've updated your connection string in the Azure environment to match the below format:
"DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=<your_storage_account_name>;EndpointSuffix=queue.core.windows.net;Credential=ManagedIdentity"
There should be no AccountKey, or SharedAccessSignature in your string.

Thanks for your input. As it is 8.0 I use the new way of referencing Storage Account. Like this:{
"IsEncrypted": false,
"Values": {
"AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
"FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated",
"Q88NotifyCron": "0 0 3 * * WED",
"Q88Cron": "0 0 7,12,17 * * *",
"QueueConnection__queueServiceUri": "https://xxx.queue.core.windows.net"
}
}
